# string interpolation for variables

Tags: groovy

I have a class of static vars

```
class Globals {
        static String SLAVE_1_LABEL = 'ruby'
        static String SLAVE_2_LABEL = 'python'
        static String SLAVE_3_LABEL = 'java'
        .....
 }
```

What is the proper way to do this:

```
labelString = Globals.SLAVE_${i}_LABEL ?: "mesos-${Globals.SLAVE_${i}_LABEL}",

Script1.groovy: 145: expecting ')', found '_LABEL' @ line 145, column 53.
    obals.SLAVE_${i}_LABEL ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Var needed double quotes

```
 Globals."SLAVE_${i}_LABEL"
```